# Unable to access react-vite app on mobile

Tags: port, vite

I am developing a react app using vite but i want to test it on mobile. I tried to host the vite app to local network and it's giving me a link but when I enter it on mobile it's saying This site can't be reached. I'm using Linux endeavouros.

I tried entering the mongodb local server link on my mobile and it returns "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port." Why am I just not able to access the vite host link. I checked the open ports and the vite port was open and it was a tcp6 while the mongo port was tcp

Comment: Please check if you have firewall enabled or not